# Scaling a data matrix to execute an algorithm

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, convergence, matrix

Suppose that I have to perform a certain algorithm (MCMC) on data that are stored in a matrix. In order to accelerate the convergence, I want to scale the centering them around 0.

What type of scaling would you suggest:

1. each row around its mean,
2. each column around its mean, or
3. each entry of the matrix around the mean of the matrix

Comment: Why do you expect scaling to accelerate convergence in the first place?

Comment: Because I'm having some problem with model averaging especially with tau parameters. I've tried to change the parametrization, the prior information (uniform and half cauchy on devst or gamma on precision), increasing the number of iteration (300k and more), but some paramters don't want to converge. I read somewhere that scaling the data could accelerate the convergence, but in this case I have bidimensional data (mortality data, that are for age and year), so I don't know on which dimension is convenient to scale. If you have better idea instead modifying data you have my attention.